# Material v5 styled component not applying styles

Tags: material-ui

I have a customized style component:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';

const CheckboxTermStyled = styled(
  ({ id, status, value, IconsComponent, onClick, ...props }) => (
    <Box className={status} display={'flex'}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <Checkbox
            id={id}
            color={'secondary'}
            onChange={onClick}
            checked={status !== ''}
            size={'small'}
            inputProps={{ value: value }}
          />
        }
        sx={{ m: 0 }}
        {...props}
      />
      {status && IconsComponent && <IconsComponent />}
    </Box>
  )
)(({ theme }) => ({
  '&.OBJECTED': {
    color: 'red',
    border: `1px solid ${theme.customProps.termStatus.objected.border}`,
    backgroundColor: theme.customProps.termStatus.objected.backgroundColor,
    '&:hover, &:focus, &:focus': {
      backgroundColor: theme.customProps.termStatus.objected.backgroundColor,
    },
    '& .MuiIconButton-root': {
      color: theme.customProps.termStatus.objected.color,
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
  },
}));

export default CheckboxTermStyled;
```

Using Chrome tools, I see this:

[image]

So I imagine that my styled component is created correctly. But styles are not being to the MuiBox... applied...

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

**styled** needs to pass the `className` to the `Box` component.

Try changing these lines:

```
const CheckboxTermStyled = styled(
  ({ id, status, value, IconsComponent, onClick, ...props }) => (
    <Box className={status} display={'flex'}>
```

...to...

```
const CheckboxTermStyled = styled(
  ({ className, id, status, value, IconsComponent, onClick, ...props }) => (
    <Box className={ className } display={'flex'}>
```